# Get data from two mysql tables in a same php file

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a PHP page for displaying data from MySQL table 'table1'.
I've added a simple visitors counter in the second PHP file, and it shows visits in another MYSQL table 'table2' in the same database.

I need to display data from 'table2' on the same PHP page where is data from 'table1'

Code for the PHP page.

```
<?php
$db_host = 'localhost'; // Server Name
$db_user = 'username'; // Username
$db_pass = 'password'; // Password
$db_name = 'database'; // Database Name

$conn = mysqli_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass, $db_name);
if (!$conn) {
    die ('Failed to connect to MySQL: ' . mysqli_connect_error());  
}

$sql = 'SELECT * 
        FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2';

$query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

if (!$query) {
    die ('SQL Error: ' . mysqli_error($conn));
}

?>
```

Okay, so I did INNER JOIN to get both tables, but how to post visitors counter data from table2 in let's say h2 tag?

Comment: you need to define on which columns you want in Join, Like "select * from table1 inner join table2 on table1.col1 = table2.col2". Check this for more https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/join.html

Comment: If your second table can be outputed in a `<h2>` I think you won't need to join your tables but to make a 2nd query. If you really need to join them, check the multiple `JOIN` types of SQL and think about how your tables are related to each other. Your question looks unclear at the moment.

Comment: So I could actually remove JOIN and add "$count = mysql_fetch_row(mysql_query("SELECT counter FROM table2"));" ?

Comment: @kuzmvnovic depends if your tables are related or not (question is really unclear). If you really need to `JOIN`, here are examples to help you understand how you should do it: [https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp)

Answer (score 1):

I don't really get your question right. 
But I think what you are doing wrong is your inner join.

Your INNER JOIN:

```
$sql = 'SELECT * 
    FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2';
```

How it should be:

```
$sql - 'SELECT * FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.column_name = table2.column_name';
```

Where the column names must have the same value.

Comment: Got it, the main problem is that table1 has columns Name|Surname|Birthday|etc. and the table2 has column counter. Table2 is just for counting visitors. I'm displaying table1 in a PHP table, but need to display counter column from table2 in h2 tag on the same page.

Comment: @kuzmvnovic Just use 2 different Querys then. One to get the person data and one for the counter. And just echo the result from the counter in the tag

Comment: That's what I need, but can't get it work. When I add $count = mysql_fetch_row(mysql_query("SELECT counter FROM table2")); and put print "$count[0]"; in h2 tag, nothing appears in h2 tag.

Comment: @kuzmvnovic  Could u pls add how you print the $count in the h2 tag?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how your tables are linked together.
JOIN is used to link a table to another on an attribute (like foreign key). You need to specify which attribute writing "SELECT * FROM table1 JOIN table2 ON table1.firstattribute = table2.secondattribute" that is equivalent to "SELECT * FROM table1, table2 WHERE table1.firstattribute = table2.secondattribute".

I think you need simply do a query on table2 filtering an attribute given from the first table1. You can do 2 queries or just one with JOIN. I'd like to have more information but here a sample

```
<?php
$db_host = 'localhost'; // Server Name
$db_user = 'username'; // Username
$db_pass = 'password'; // Password
$db_name = 'database'; // Database Name

$conn = mysqli_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass, $db_name);
if (!$conn) {
    die ('Failed to connect to MySQL: ' . mysqli_connect_error());  
}

$sql = 'SELECT * 
        FROM table1 JOIN table2 ON table1.attr1 = table2.attr2';

$query = $conn->query($sql);

if (!$query) {
    die ('SQL Error: ' . mysqli_error($conn));
}

if(mysqli_num_rows($query)>0){
    //we can create an object that has the same attribute of both tables
    $object = $query->fetch_object();
    //for example $object has views of table2.views
    echo '<h2>Views:' . $object->views . '</h2>';

}


?>
```

So, if I understood good you only need use [fetch_object](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-object.php) and a correct form of [JOIN](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/join.html)

Comment: If you didn't you need to insert into table2 an attribute that is table1's foreign key